# Processing Accelerometer Data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, accelerometer

I have accelerometer data Log, the data contain (accX, accY, accZ,timestamp)
The data look like [image]
I am so confused how to processing it in R.
I have two questions:

1. Is there any library for handle this data? I want plot it like time
   series data and analysis it.
2. How to process the timestamp? because the timestamp is not every
   second but milisecond.

Please anyone can give me some light?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To answer your two specific questions:

1) There are many packages for time series analysis. See here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

2) There are many ways to process the time stamp data. @bjoseph gives you some very good advice in his response. The `lubridate` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) is very good at handling time data with somewhat more sensible functions than the `POSIX` set. `ggplot2` (http://ggplot2.org/) plots time series data quite sensibly as well.

Answer (score 0):

The classes POSIXlt and POSIXct exist in R for manipulating calendar times and dates. See more information here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html

In your specific case you need to may need to modify your system time to include milliseconds:

```
 test <- "2014-07-09 15:03:33:252"
 test
 [1]"2014-07-09 15:03:33:252"
 options("digits.secs"=6)
 Sys.time()
 [1] "2014-07-23 11:16:32.480932 EDT"
 as.POSIXlt(test)
 [1] "2014-07-09 15:03:33 EDT"
 test
 [1] "2014-07-09 15:03:33:252"
 time.test <- as.POSIXlt(test)
 class(time.test)
 [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
 time.test
 [1] "2014-07-09 15:03:33 EDT"
```

To apply this to the entire column of your data.table you can run:

```
dt$timecolumn <- as.POSIXlt(dt$timecolumn)
```

where time column is the name of the column with the times in it.

If you need help importing the data from excel, a [good guide](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import):

```
> library(gdata)                   # load gdata package 
> help(read.xls)                   # documentation 
> mydata = read.xls("mydata.xls")  # read from first sheet
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you didnot answer my main question

Comment: Sorry, what's your main question? I'd be happy to try to answer that.

Comment: I don't believe you need a special package to read or plot time data.

You can just plot it normally with plot(x,y) and specify that your axes are using posix data, this article is a good resource http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/graphics/html/axis.POSIXct.html

Comment: Is there any library for handle this data? I want plot it like time series data and analysis it. I want to plot it, time in x axis, and accX in Y axis,etc

Comment: Sure. For the basic plots and data inputs you don't need any special libraries. Just

`axis.POSIXct(side=1, dt$timecolumn)`
`plot(dt$timecolumn, dt$accX)`

does that help?